# CakePHP - Cannot access logged in user's password in Model using Authcomponent::user

Tags: cakephp, authentication, cakephp-2.0, change-password

I started trying out CakePHP a few months ago and I'm now attempting to create a "change password page" for logged in users. I have a form consisting of these fields: current password, new password and new password confirmation. For the current password, I want to validate that it matches the password of the logged in user, as a rule within the user Model. **I know that I can get information of the logged in user with this: `AuthComponent::user()`. However, it provides me every field of the model except the password.**

I know that `Auth->login()` is responsible for setting the session variables for the logged in user, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here that only the password field cannot be accessed:

```
public function login() {

    if ($this->request->is('POST')) {
        if($this->Auth->login()) {
            $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Your username/password combination was incorrect.');
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my login view:

```
<h2>Login</h2>
<?php 
echo $this->Form->create('Promoter');
echo $this->Form->input('username');
echo $this->Form->input('password', array('type' => 'password'));
echo $this->Form->end('Login');?>
```

I'm using the Promoter model as the user, which i set in the AppController:

```
public $components = array(
    'Auth'=>array(
        ...
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array('userModel' => 'Promoter')
        ),
        'authorize' => array('Controller')
    )
);
```

I can resort to validating the password in the Controller, but that would be giving up :) Please tell me if I need to provide more code to clarify the issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably not doing anything wrong, this is most likely a security feature. There is no reason to keep a password in your session.

Secondly, even if it was in session, it would be encrypted (or at least I hope so, if it's not you should change that immediately!). So you still couldn't do a simple comparison.

To compare the old password, you should query your `Promoter` model, and get the hashed password from there, then hash the old password from your "change password" form, and finally compare the hashed results.

Answer (score 0):

Because cake doesn't store the password in the session:

lib/Cake/Component/Auth/BaseAuthenticate.php line 94

```
unset($user[$fields['password']]);
```